# sorting rows according to a row pattern

Tags: r, sorting, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I want to re-arrange the rows of a dataframe that looks like this:

```
qs=c("q11", "q22", "q2", "q6", "q10")
ans=rep(1,times=length(qs))
df=data.frame(qs,ans)
arrange(df,qs)

 qs ans
1 q10   1
2 q11   1
3  q2   1
4 q22   1
5  q6   1
```

However, I want the sorting of the rows to look in the much more logical order, such as this:

```
 qs ans
1  q2   1
2  q6   1
3 q10   1
4 q11   1
5 q22   1
```

Can someone help me with this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use R base:

```
df <- df[order(as.integer(gsub("q", "", as.character(df$qs)))), ]
```

For you example `df`, this gives:

```
   qs ans
3  q2   1
4  q6   1
5 q10   1
1 q11   1
2 q22   1
```

You might note that rownames are not 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 after reordering; you can do:

```
rownames(df) <- 1:nrow(df)
```

to make it look nice:

```
   qs ans
1  q2   1
2  q6   1
3 q10   1
4 q11   1
5 q22   1
```

Comment: Your answer helped, Thanks. As already commented to akun, a related question  to this is what if the rows are of this form 'qs=c("Q.1a", "Q.1b", "Q.10a", "Q.10b", "Q.10c", "Q.6a", "Q.6b")'  in such a case neither answers worked.

Answer (score 2):

We use `mixedorder` from `gtools` after converting the 'qs' to `character` class

```
library(gtools)
df1 <- `row.names<-`(df[mixedorder(as.character(df$qs)),], NULL)
df1
#   qs ans
#1  q2   1
#2  q6   1
#3 q10   1
#4 q11   1
#5 q22   1
```

---

Or we can use `base R` as well by removing the non-numeric characters with `gsub`, convert to `numeric`, `order` the rows.

```
df[order(as.numeric(gsub("\\D+", "", df$qs))),]
```

Comment: No offense akrun, but why do you use `\`row.names<-\`` making code much harder to read and maintain (especially for newbies) instead of a second line?

Comment: @docendodiscimus  Because I noticed that the other poster already posted the `rownames(df) <- ..` and if I use that it becomes redundant.  Also, there is a danger that the OP might think that my answer is not complete, so I took the chance to do that and avoiding possible plagiarism.

Comment: @akrun Your answer helped, Thanks. A related question to this is what if the rows are of this form 'qs=c("Q.1a", "Q.1b", "Q.10a", "Q.10b", "Q.10c", "Q.6a", "Q.6b")'  in such a case neither answers worked.

Comment: @msh855 Perhaps `qs[mixedorder(sub(".*\\.", "", qs))]
#[1] "Q.1a"  "Q.1b"  "Q.6a"  "Q.6b"  "Q.10a" "Q.10b" "Q.10c"`

Comment: @akrun, No offense, it was a mistake:).